# BNRPersistence on the iPhone, and NSDocument

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsdocument

I'm trying to get BNRPersistence running in an iPhone app, but I'm having a problem that I have no idea how to solve. Keep in mind I'm relatively new to iPhone dev.

The problem is that BNRStoreDocument subclasses NSDocument, which exists in the Cocoa framework and thus isn't available on the iPhone. So obviously I'm getting compile errors that it can't find NSDocument. The developer of BNRPersistence states that it works on the iPhone, so I'm sure there a solution, I just don't what it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iphone Demo project does not have BNRStoreDocument in it but just BNRStore. I think is reasonable to assume that BNRStoreDocument is only available when running under Cocoa on a Mac OS X.

The BNRStore is an analog of NSPersistantStore. I'm pretty sure that's what you should be using on the iPhone.